# How to drive such a small motor?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I have a *very* small stepper 4 pin 2 phase stepper motor, I need to know what's the most convenient way to connect wires to it in order to drive it (as I have about 300 of those I need to drive).
Here's the motor:
[image: My small motor]

I'm hoping your experience can help me.

Comment: Your problem is about how to drive this motor, or how to connect wires?

Comment: As HOPE mention you might want to add a few details to the question. I suggest adding a link to a datasheet. Also check out this link [All About Stepper Motors](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/all-about-stepper-motors.pdf). This link might help you get started. Electrically I suggest that you use H-bridge driver and micro controller to drive the motor

Comment: you drive it carefully.

Comment: These are seen soldered to a small rigid PCB with wires or a connector or alternately to a flexible PCB that doubles as the 'wires' and is plugged into the controller board.  For 300 pieces you could possibly justify ordering suitable flex PCBs made, regular PCBs would cost very little as they will be small.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about how you need to mount these motors.  My first reaction is to make a PC board with holes for the 4 leads, then add whatever other mounting holes you need to hold the assembly in place.  You could integrate the drive circuitry on the same board.